# Finding duplicate documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents whose ids are randomly generated. The issue here is I need to find the duplicates amongst these documents. I have three fields which should not be identical for two documents. So how to check for duplicates based on multiple fields?

Sample documents

```
document 1 = {
"process" : "business",
"processId" : 5433321,
"country" : "US"
}

document 2 = {
"process" : "operations",
"processId" : 334233,
"country" : "UK"
}

document 3 = {
"process" : "business",
"processId" : 5433321,
"country" : "US"
}
```

Here as you can see, document 1 and document 3 are the same, but they are having different Ids in my database,so exist as separate documents. So on run I need to find the above as duplicates and if possible keep only one.

Comment: Can you show a sample document with those fields you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The best option here would be to model your document around doc ID. Now for each unique document , create a docID which is a hash of the content of the document. This makes sure that only one unique document exists across the index. Next use _create API to create documents. This will fail all requests on over write document with same document ID.

You can further read about other duplication issues and its solutions [here](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).